# modify page table read/write bits to modify system call table

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, page-tables

I want to modify the address of the __NR_fork entry is the system call table

So i will make something like: sys_call_table_addr[__NR_fork] = newaddress;

But I want to change the read/write bits in the page table to be able to modify it
Any hints on how to do that?

Comment: Hi @Omar-Osman, did my answer on this or your other post solve your questions? If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how this will work for your purposes, but in general the mechanisms for page tables are:

1. A page table walk to find the page table entry (`pte`). Two ways I know how are manually, like how it's done in the `__handle_mm_fault()` function defined [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/memory.c#L4436) or with a `walk_page_range()` call that does the walk for you with other helper walk functions defined [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/pagewalk.c#L379). Note that `__handle_mm_fault()` leaves the last step of converting `pmd` to `pte` to the `handle_pte_fault()` function.
2. Functions for modifying the page table entry (`pte`) bits. Many relevant functions including `pte_set_flags()`, `pte_mkclean()`, `pte_mkwrite()`, etc. are defined [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable.h#L334)